# Ionic project failed to build on Xcode12 exited with code 65

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, xcode12

This is the error I get while trying to release build my ionic project with:

'ionic cordova build --release ios --verbose'

[image]

on Xcode shows this:

[image]

This is the project configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i only had to update plugins to the latest versions, using 'npm outdated' and then update everything one by one, then type 'npm install' was able tu build succesfully afterwards